# Erase a branch that was never pushed

Tags: mercurial, branch, backout

I've just found out that someone committed some time ago some changes locally, that was revision #410, now the right version is #638... that created a branch in that person's mercurial history, and I want to get rid of it... I tried to execute an Undo > Backout... but it won't let me...

The error message I got is:

[image: error message]

That person's Mercurial history:

[image: Branch that was never pushed]

What can I do to get rid of that branch? The changes that it was supposed to do were already made some revisions ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error appears to be because you are on a different branch then the following will probably work:

```
hg up -r 410
hg backout -r 410
hg merge
hg commit
```

However, this will add an irrelevant changeset and a merge that you don't care about.  You could simply do this, instead:

```
hg clone -r tip repo repo1      # This should strip the unwanted changeset
cp repo/.hg/hgrc repo1/.hg/hgrc # This will copy any repo customizations
rm -rf repo                     # Delete original repo
mv repo1 repo                   # Replace original repo
```

The above commands are Unix/Linux commands and it appears you might be on Windows.  If you are, just replace the commands with the Windows equivalent.  If you don't understand, I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [strip command](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Strip) of the mq-extension like: `hg strip 410`